# Sparql Transaction

Tags: transactions, sparql, rdf, triplestore, shacl

I want to insert multiple objects into a triplestore like Jena fuseki or virtuoso.

In my case, the subject equal to a primary key. It is similar to a relational database.  How can I make sure that the subject is only present once or is already in use?  Can an ASK be combined with an insert in Sparql? Or can a key be generated?

As long as you use an instance of the backend you can make sure that the subject only exists once, but with more instance the query and insert must occur simultaneously to save the transaction.

Comment: ??? An RDF graph contains a set of RDF triples. I don't know what you're asking about primary keys. What means "insert multiple objects"? You have to insert RDF triples. Just use the same URI for the same entity. It is RDF not a relational database.

Comment: SPARQL does not support transactions, per se. The rest of your question is somewhat unclear, made more so by the last paragraph. RDF and SPARQL do not provide a way to "use a subject once", not only because a subject/entity typically has multiple predicates/attributes which might each have multiple objects/values. If you want to populate a SQL table, then do so with SQL tools, and use Virtuoso or other tool to access that table through an RDF View (or Linked Data View). Your question *might* be made clearer if you describe your actual goal, rather than this specific step you see as necessary.

Comment: Yes I know. But if I want to insert a new object with multiple Triples like <uri1> ?p ?o, <uri1> ?p2 ?o2 and so on,  How can I be sure that the Uri has not already been used?

Comment: Let me try explaining again. The goal is to make sure that users create the new triple, only create a triple if the subject is not available in the Triplestore. 
Example:

 <person1> a schema:person; schema:givenName "Robert".
<person2> a schema:person; schema:givenName "Bob".

If someone:

INSERT DATA
{ 
  <person1> a schema:person; 
                      schema:givenName "Alexa".
}

How can I prevent this insert from being executed?

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Well, in that case, you have to check before inserting the triples. Ideally, use `ASK {<uri1> ?p ?o}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update can be of the form `INSERT .. WHERE` and the `WHERE` part can include a test of whether to update or not.

The SPARQL protocol for update requires actions to be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

The SPARQL standards themselves do not provide any support for transactions. However, Virtuoso and many other RDF databases support the [Eclipse RDF4J](http://rdf4j.org/) APIs, which have full transactional support (disclosure: I'm on the RDF4J development team). An example using RDF4J transactions in Java would be something like this:

```java
 Repository rep = ... ; // the Repository object is your database

 // open a connection to the database
 try(RepositoryConnection conn = rep.getConnection) {
     conn.begin(); // start a new transaction
     ... 
     // do a query
     boolean success = conn.prepareBooleanQuery("ASK ...").evaluate(); 
     if (!success) { 
        conn.rollback();
     }
     else {
        // add some data
        conn.add(...);
        conn.commit();
     }
 }
```

For more information on how transactions work with RDF4J, see the [documentation](http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming/#_transactions).

If you're not working in Java, you can also work with transaction via the [RDF4J REST API](http://docs.rdf4j.org/rest-api), which is an extension of the SPARQL Protocol.

As an aside: the above is just to answer the "how do I do transactions" part of your question really. There may be other, better mechanisms available than doing an ASK query for the kind of constraint validation you're looking for. SHACL, the shapes constraint language, might be what you need. Various tools and platforms have (partial or full) support for SHACL validation. You can read more about [RDF4J SHACL support](http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming/#_validation_with_shacl) here.